# What is the difference between upsampling and up conversion (done during signal transmission)? Also is upconversion different from modulation?

Tags: frequency, modulation

Up sampling is when you increase the sample rate of a continuous signal. Modulation is when you, by multiplying with a carrier, shift the base frequency of a signal. But what is up conversion? How is it related with the above mentioned terms?

Answer (score 2):

Your first sentence is not correct.  The terminology of 'sample rate conversion' operations is often misused.  I suggest you replace your first sentence with, "Interpolation is when you increase the sample rate of a DISCRETE signal sequence."  I'd also replace your second sentence with, "Modulation is when you, by multiplying with a carrier frequency, shift a signal's spectral components up in frequency by a fixed amount." (The term "modulation" is typically used when talking about continuous signals.)  As far as I understand the terminology, "up-conversion" is when you shift the spectral components of a discrete sequence up in frequency by a fixed amount. [-Rick Lyons-]

Comment: In digital communications, modulation is the mapping from bits to symbols (pulse amplitudes). For example, in BPSK modulation one maps a bit 0 to an amplitude $A$, and a bit 1 to an amplitude $-A$. Upconversion means shifting the analog baseband modulated signal up to radio frequency for transmission.

Comment: Upvoting this answer because it is RICK F'ING LYONS.